# Opening a window in other method than `DialogBox`

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a dialog `IDD_WINDOW_INFO` that has to be opened when the user clicks a button or a menu item in my C++ Win32 application. The method that I use to open the dialog is in the following line:

```
DialogBox(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_WINDOW_INFO), hMainWindow, WindowInfoProc);
```

but my problem is that when that dialog box opens, the user cannot operate with the main window of my application. So what can I do to have both windows active?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are calling `DialogBox` which shows the dialog modally. When a modal dialog is shown, the other owning windows are disabled and only the modal dialog can accept input. That is the very essence and intent of a modal dialog. The idea is that you can interact only with the dialog, and cannot interact with the other windows.

Another answer suggests passing `NULL` as the `hWndParent` parameter to `DialogBox`. That's not the solution. That will result in you having an unowned window. Yes, you will be able to interact with the main window, but when you do so your main window will appear on top of the dialog. That's because the ownership is set incorrectly. I recommend that you read about [window ownership to better understand the issue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#owned_windows).

The correct solution to your problem is to show a modeless dialog. A modeless dialog allows you to interact with the other windows in your application. And that's exactly what you ask for in the question.

You show modeless dialogs by calling `CreateDialog` followed by `ShowWindow`. This MSDN article shows an example: [Using Dialog Boxes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms644996.aspx#modeless_box).

Comment: it is a dialog in an `.rc` file

Comment: Of course it is. That's why you are able to call `DialogBox`. And you can equally call `CreateDialog`. For the life of me I cannot understand the downvote on this answer.

Comment: Now, after your edit, the answer fits my question perfectly ;) Thank you.

Comment: Well thank you. Even before the edit, the answer fitted perfectly, in my view. Original answer said to call CreateDialog/ShowWindow to show a modeless dialog, and that is what you need. All I've done is to add some explanation, and to debunk the misleading suggestion to show an unowned dialog box. However, the answer is better now that I've added more explanation.

Comment: The issue of window ownership is, by and large, very poorly understood. Most GUI frameworks shield developers from it. However, it's incredibly important to get it right. So it's worth spending a bit of time reading the MSDN article I linked to and finding other expositions on ownership.

Answer (score 2):

If I recall correctly, you can either pass NULL instead of the handle to the parent window or change the dialogbox type in the resource editor.

That is an easy way to do it, however the following is certainly better - since having an unowned dialog isn't your best choice.
The point is that DialogBox() will create a modal dialog window, while CreateDialog does not. Modal dialogs disable the parent window.
From MSDN: *A modeless dialog box neither disables the owner window nor sends messages to it.*
That should solve your problem.

```
CreateDialog(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_WINDOW_INFO), hMainWindow, WindowInfoProc);

ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
```

Comment: it works with `NULL` handle, but now the dialog, doesn't stand on top of the main window of the application. (Both of them are SystemModalDialog and Topmost), what can I do?

Comment: Use the SetWindowPos() function with the HWND_TOPMOST flag. This forces a window to stay on top. See MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: This is bad advice, both in the answer, and the comments. @Victor, please disregard it. The problem is that the dialog is being shown modally. That's the root of the problem. Passing `NULL` for the dialog owner just means you have an incorrectly owned dialog. That's no better. The problem is that we need to show the dialog modeless rather than modal. So, let's do just that.

Comment: @ArthurMcKnight, please, write a line of code in your answer to help me, because I am a beginner. Then, I will mark you answer.

Comment: `HWND_TOPMOST` doesn't help at all. Now your window is on top of all windows, even ones in other applications. You need your window to be owned by your main window, which is why you cannot pass `NULL` as the window owner. I could explain more about this if you are interested in learning.

Comment: At least your edit is better. But you are still giving out the awful advice of showing a modal dialog unowned. Why don't you just remove that in an edit? And then you could perhaps add some explanatory text rather than just a couple of lines of code without explanation.

Comment: @David Heffernan: A modal dialog box without a parent window certainly isn't the best idea - however it's a solution that works just fine in some circumstances. Of course, a modeless dialog is a better solution.

Comment: In which circumstances does unowned modal dialog work well? Why would you ever prefer that to modeless dialog? Can you tell me any situation where it is to be preferred? I can't understand why you are clinging on to that suggestion.

Comment: One case would be when showing 2 windows side by side. Works just fine. It wouldn't be my first choice but still - it works.

Comment: This situation demands that dialog is always above the main window. That's clear from the comments. And that needs ownership. Anyway, I think I've made my point, and well done for the edits. They improve things. I remove my downvote.